# aws_encryption_sdk python infinity loop

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I've got this piece of code from the official AWS documentation and just put my filenames and kms key:

```
    with open('/tmp/DAILY.csv', 'rb') as pt_file, open('/tmp/DAILY.enc', 'wb') as ct_file:
    with aws_encryption_sdk.stream(mode='e', source=pt_file, key_provider=kms_key_provider) as encryptor:
        for chunk in encryptor:
            ct_file.write(chunk)
```

This runs inside AWS Lambda and the file DAILY.csv is in /tmp (it is delivered there from a code above and I can see it). The file is not very big.
The problem I hit is that AWS Lambda runs quite long and timeouts without finishing the encryption.

Comment: The README says the frame size can have an impact on the performace. Have you tried adjusting it? I think it's done via the `frame_length` kwarg, the default is 4096.

Comment: Just did it and the resut is the same

Comment: You can also try increasing the memory allocated to the Lambda - that will give it a more powerful vCPU. BTW how long does it take when you run this piece of code locally on your machine?

Comment: If I run it locally on my laptop it works like a charm